# Как сделать :first-child в css3?

Tags: css3

```html
<div class="header_text">
 <img src="images/goriy.jpg" alt="">
 <p>Nibipu</p>
 <p>Bringing youy closer to pixel perfection.</p>
</div>
```

Как написать стиль например для моего класса .header_text для первого абзаца p ?

Comment: Vitalik Slobodyanuyk, не красиво оставлять людей без внимания...  Ты хотя бы ответы принимай, когда тебе помогают... 10 вопросов  ни одного принятого ответа....

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68269/discussion-on-question-by-vitalik-slobodyanuyk---first-child--css3).

Answer (score 4):

```
.header_text p:first-of-type{
    color: red;
}
```

Подробнее здесь - [:first-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)